# NDVI and NCC(Normalize Correlation Coeff)

Tags: image-processing

Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI) and Normalize Correlation Coefficient are two very popular techinques used in Image processing, But how can I implement them in my project using python.(mainly numpy and pytorch)?

I tried to look for some code availble but could not find any.

```
'''
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Step 1: Read the images
channel_460 = cv2.imread('/home/aritra/Thesis/Tomato_dataset/train/room_17@plant_1@date_06-12-2019@time_18.36.3@Image_460.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
channel_540 = cv2.imread('/home/aritra/Thesis/Tomato_dataset/train/room_17@plant_1@date_06-12-2019@time_18.36.3@Image_540.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
channel_630 = cv2.imread('/home/aritra/Thesis/Tomato_dataset/train/room_17@plant_1@date_06-12-2019@time_18.36.3@Image_630.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
channel_850 = cv2.imread('/home/aritra/Thesis/Tomato_dataset/train/room_17@plant_1@date_06-12-2019@time_18.36.3@Image_850.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
channel_980 = cv2.imread('/home/aritra/Thesis/Tomato_dataset/train/room_17@plant_1@date_06-12-2019@time_18.36.3@Image_980.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Step 2: Calculate NDVI image
NIR = channel_980.astype(np.float32)
Red = channel_630.astype(np.float32)

NDVI = (NIR - Red) / (NIR + Red + 1e-10)  # Adding a small constant to avoid division by zero

import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ... (previous code)

# Step 4: Compute Normalized Correlation Coefficient (NCC) between channel 540 and NDVI
I540_original = channel_540.astype(np.float32)

# Initialize variables to keep track of the best NCC and corresponding threshold
best_ncc = -1
best_threshold = 0
best_ndvi_thresholded = None
best_i540_thresholded = None

# Iterate over a range of thresholds
for threshold in np.arange(0, 1, 0.01):
    ndvi_binary = (NDVI > threshold).astype(np.float32)
    i540_binary = (I540_original > threshold).astype(np.float32)
    
    # Calculate mean and standard deviation for normalization
    mean_i540 = np.mean(i540_binary)
    mean_ndvi_binary = np.mean(ndvi_binary)
    std_i540 = np.std(i540_binary)
    std_ndvi_binary = np.std(ndvi_binary)
    
    # Calculate NCC
    ncc = np.sum((i540_binary - mean_i540) * (ndvi_binary - mean_ndvi_binary) / (std_i540 * std_ndvi_binary))
    
    # Update best NCC, threshold, and thresholded images if the current NCC is higher
    if ncc > best_ncc:
        best_ncc = ncc
        best_threshold = threshold
        best_ndvi_thresholded = ndvi_binary
        best_i540_thresholded = i540_binary

# Display the results
plt.subplot(1, 4, 1)
plt.imshow(NDVI, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original NDVI')

plt.subplot(1, 4, 2)
plt.imshow(best_ndvi_thresholded, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Thresholded NDVI')

plt.subplot(1, 4, 3)
plt.imshow(I540_original, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original I540')

plt.subplot(1, 4, 4)
plt.imshow(best_i540_thresholded, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Thresholded I540')

plt.show()

'''
```

here is what I tried. But still the thresholded images are not working